# Creating a function with a condition in Python

Tags: python, function, if-statement, math

I need to create a function named 'Bernoulli' that should take 2 input variables 'rr' and 'p' and should return a value of 1 if rr is less than or equal to p and a value of 0 if rr is greater than p.

The code I have produced so far is this:

```
rr=float(input())
p=float(input())
def bernoulli(rr,p):
  if rr<=p:
    return 'X=1'
  else:
    return 'X=0'
```

I am not sure how correct this is.

Upon running tests I get this feedback:
Your program took too long to execute.
Make sure that it isn't waiting for input and that there is no infinite loop.

Comment: You never call the function. Nothing inside the function block will run. The program will be over very quickly in such a case, maybe the error is misleading in this corner case or there's more you're not showing.

Comment: The feedback says it all: *Make sure that it isn't waiting for input*

Comment: Even then, nothing gets computed here.

Comment: `bernoulli = float.__le__` Done and done.

Answer (score 0):

```
rr=float(input())
p=float(input())
def bernoulli(rr,p):
    if rr<=p:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

x = bernoulli(rr,p)
print(x)
```

However, if you are simply checking if one number is bigger than the other, it might make more sense down the line to use `True` and `False` because comparing them will be a shorter line of code later on. `if x == False` That being in the logical sense that we understand true to be positive and false to be negative. You might forget which way round the 1 and the 0 are ordered :)

Comment: `False` is not negative. `False` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Swift answered this in the same way I would approach this. The reason your code is not executing, is because it is never used. You must call a function to use it.

Here is how I did it:

```
rr=float(input())
p=float(input())
def bernoulli(rr,p):
  if rr<=p:
    return 'X=1'
  else:
    return 'X=0'

function_response = bernoulli(rr,p)

print(function_response)
```